# Simple Stepper motor for my experiment?

Tags: stepper-motor, magnetics

To graduate (Grade 12 or Year 12), I need to do an self-thought experiment in Physics. I decided to do something about stepper motor because I learned that they use this type of motor for robot arms.

Of course, I know that I cannot build a real entire stepper motor. However, I was wondering if i can build a much simpler one with less stator and rotor teeth.

I asked this to my physics teacher, but he isn't convinced about this idea.

My first question would be, **Is it possible to make a simpler stepper motor?** like this one.

[image: this but with more stator and rotor teeth]

If yes, I am also a bit unsure about what will be my independent and dependent variables. I planned to make the current my independent variable and measure the angle of the magnet, since by energizing multiple coil at the same time, the angle will change.

**Are these variables ok for my experiment or should i choose a different one ?**

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Pingu

Comment: Think again . A typical stepper with 200 pulse per rev has 200 pole pairs per rev not 2

Comment: In actuality stepper motors are mostly used in hobby robot arms, not industrial ones.  But yes, you can make a simple stepper.  Most electronically commutated motors, including for example hobby brushless motors that you can build from kits by re-using CD ROM spindle motor cans and laminations, are notably "stepp-y" when run *open loop*, even if they are actually designed to be run (and only produce useful torque) with closed loop control where the coils are switched based on an impression of their movement, rather than by arbitrary command like stepper.

Comment: Check on hackaday, someone recently made something using mostly circuit board material.  Non-ideal motor structures will be weak due to the big gaps in the magnetic circuit, but they can work for lecture-demo concept illustration.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So you are saying that because of the non ideal motor structure, the data collected from the experiment would not be reliable ?

Comment: It sounds like you're exploring microstepping behavior.  The data will be valid for the device experimented on.  It will be only distantly extensible to those actually used in motion systems.  Keep in mind externally applied force will be a factor, too.  Incidentally, many traditional car instrument gauges use a stepper like structure with orthogonal coils driven in some relation to the sine and cosine of the angle the pointer should  seek... you might visit a salvage yard or seek a photo/drawing of one.

Comment: What's your plan for the experiment? Also by "self-thought" perhaps you mean self-taught? A thought experiment is an experiment that you don't actually do, only think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend tweaking your choice of independent variable slightly. I would consider each coil to be either ON, OFF, or ON(Reversed). I would then consider *which coils are energized* to be the independent variable.

I think this is a great experiment. You should be able to build a working model similar to the diagram you posted. You can use toggle switches to control the coils and "step" the motor.

A DPDT toggle switch can be hooked up so that middle is off, up is current in one direction, and down is current in the opposite direction.
See [here](http://www.robotroom.com/DPDT-Bidirectional-Motor-Switch.html).

Comment: You are describing full step (or full and half step) control where a coil is either fully on or off for some standard value of current.   However, there's also a scheme called microstepping where the current is adjusted in each coil to achieve an intermeidate angle, that sounds more like what the poster is getting at.  The sine/cosine type car dashboard displays are an extreme - only really one or two steps, it's all microstep gradations.   Current control can be either analog, or more common a chopping or PWM digital fraction.

Comment: Which would be a good choice depends a lot on what sort of control electronics the poster is comfortable with - at flipping a switch level, you are absolutely right.  At being willing to play with a little MCU board / Arduino and a stepper chip or H bridge, intermediate currents are plausible and give more to measure.

Comment: If needing to stay with basic switch control as proposed here, something that can still give decent experimental data is to look at holding torque and angular displacement under load before the point at which it jumps to the next cog position; simplistically speaking, you mount a stiff, lighweight lever arm on the motor and use it to hang a weight at a radius...

Comment: @Chris Yes that could be interesting, but I think it makes sense to start with half stepping the motor before getting into micro-stepping. I think most of the challenge with this will be mechanical design of the "motor" anyway.